# How to install MikTeX packages outside of install directory?

Tags: miktex

Is it possible (and if so how) to configure MikTeX to install packages outside of the install directory of MikTeX itself?

For example, say I have a user-only (`--shared=no`) install of MikTeX to my home directory on the system partition, *e.g.* `C:\Users\<name>\Appdata\Local\Programs\MikTeX`.

However, I want packages installed to another drive (say, "H:"), both during setup and subsequent updates/additional package installs.

Is this possible, and if so how?

For context: MikTeX will be virtualised under App-V with its own virtual file system to which the user will not have write access.  The user's C: drive likewise is ephemeral because we are using non-persistent virtual machines.  Users have a home directory on an intranet share, mapped to a local letter (say, "H:").

Apologies for the [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64584181/user-install-of-app-v-miktex-on-non-persistent-vm-with-shared-package-repo) from SO but it occurred to me too late that tex.stackexchange is the more appropriate community.  Will delete other post if required.

Comment: The updates can also contain miktex packages with binaries.  I don't think that the install location can be split to install one part of the packages in c and the other in h. Either install everything in H or do a shared installation with a minimal set in c. But then you will have to update c regularly too.

Comment: But the best place to ask is the miktex github.

Comment: Shared install means multi-user install to a single system, right?  Not possible, since everybody gets their own dedicated non-persistent VM.  Cheers, though, I'll go ask there.